# Value of the 3 prime numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Here's the question

> The 3 prime numbers $P,Q,R$ have a value where the product of themselves is 19 times larger than the sum of itself.Find $P^2+Q^2+R^2$.

It means that $19(P+Q+R)=PQR$

Since $P,Q,R$ MUST be an integer,so with the given equation of $P+Q+R=\frac {PQR} {19}$,one of the numbers MUST be 19.From here,I have no idea but just to use Guess and Check.I want a mathematical working other than the guessing style.(Like simultaneous equation or any other working.)

But you can check your answer here.

$P=19$
$Q=3$
$R=11$ (With no order)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you said, one of them must be $19$. Without loss of generality, take $P=19$. Then, we get,

$$19+Q+R=QR\implies 19+1=1-Q-R+QR=(1-Q)(1-R)\\ \implies (1-Q)(1-R)=20$$

$$20=(\pm 1)\times (\pm 20)=(\pm 2)\times (\pm 10)=(\pm 4)\times (\pm 5)$$

Checking all the possible factor cases yields us that the only possible prime solutions for $Q,R$ is w.l.o.g $Q=3~,~R=11$.

Comment: You should also check with $(\pm 20)\times (\pm 1)~,~(\pm 10)\times (\pm 2)~,~(\pm 4)\times (\pm 5)$ for completeness' sake. Bottom line, those are the only possible prime solutions.

Comment: Thanks.I got it.Took me a moment to understand your possible factors.

Comment: @ministic2001, Ah, well, I'm glad you got it. :)

Comment: is there another way to find the sum of the squares as the question asks for *without* finding the individual values?

Comment: @danimal, that's an interesting question. Let me see if I can find some way for that.

Comment: I disagree the requirement to put \pm as the minus is unnecessary. Because the fact that we are fining a prime nunber, which is positive

Comment: @ministic2001, there are cases where even though the factors are negative, you have positive values of $Q,R$, like the case of $(-4)\times (-5)$ gives w.l.o.g $Q=5,R=6$. But this case is not acceptable since $R=6$ is not a prime.

Comment: What I mean is, your input for 2 value as lets say its -10,-2.Then value Q and R is will be 9 and -1, which are not prime number.

Comment: @ministic2001, Check your arithmetic again. The case you mentioned gives us,$$1-Q=-10\implies Q=11\quad\textrm{and}\quad 1-R=-2\implies R=3$$

Comment: Okay, you are right.Thanks for telling me.